# How to count total number of segments in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, segments

I want to count total number of segments in codeigniter so I can display error if user/visitor enter additional segment in my url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked the [**manual**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) yet? There is such method that will get the total segments. `$this->uri->total_segments()`

Or also you can use `$this->uri->segment_array()`.

```
$total = count($this->uri->segment_array());
```